# Drawable as Background for CardView

Tags: android, android-layout

the CardView ( android.support.v7.cardview ) stays white even though I set a backround drawable via android:backround - The documentation gives me the feeling that it should work. No Idea what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: looks like it is not possible. Take a look here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77843

Answer (score 73):

I know this is an old question, but I have a simple solution - just make the first child of your *CardView* an ImageView and specify the *scale type* to *fitXY*. You can get rid of the extra CardView padding by setting *cardElevation* and *cardMaxElevation* to `0dp`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/your_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <... your layout

    .../>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without giving up the shadow from the elevation?

Comment: Tks bro, u saved me so much !!!

Answer (score 20):

for drawable or color just use:

```
cvSellerShopp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_add_image);
```

for color use:

```
 cvSellerShopp.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
```

but this one does not produce the intended results

Answer (score 15):

Make Cardview will host one viewgroup for eg relative layout in this case and then simply set any background to relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/list_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_container_bg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

           <!--Add cardview contents-->

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 15):

I got this working by adding a linearlayout in the cardview and then setting cardPreventCornerOverlap to false in the cardview.

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/result_cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    >

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

       <!-- your views -->

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 8):

The command I used was:

```
cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_view_bg);
```

where **card_view_bg** is a custom XML resource file.

If you have some layouts inside the card view and these layouts are overlapping with the margins of the card view then you might need a separate custom background resource file for the layouts like the one I used for the card view background itself.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_container_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/yourbackground"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <!--Add cardview contents-->

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark

here you can set any color or make it transparent by giving color transparent
and if u wand some drawable like image or svg put RelativeLayout background

Answer (score 4):

You can use LinearLayout or Relative layout inside CardView and set drawable background  it  like below :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card6"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card4"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/card_bg"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card6Image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card6Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Daily Check In"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card6Description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Just Check in Daily and Earn Credits"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Below is my Drawable resource file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerColor="#555994"
    android:endColor="#b5b6d2"
    android:startColor="#555994"
    android:type="linear" />

<corners
    android:radius="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can set foreground as follow for the card view to set custom bg

```
android:foreground="@drawable/bg"
```

and here is the transparent bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#d9d9d9" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 possible solutions.

1. Setting background programmatically:

> ```
> cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background)
> ```

2. Add some child to cardview that will fill cardview's bounds and set background on it:

> ```
> <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
> ...>
>      <ConstraintLayout
>         android:background="@drawable/background"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="0dp"
>         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
> </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
> ```

This way you can also give images some shape that you can configure by the shape of cardview. Disadvantage is that it is bad for performance.

Answer (score 0):

if you want change background color on cardView just add this code on your cardview XML

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/whatever_color_you"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
cardView.setForeground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scard_background);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the below line in your xml file.

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@drawable/your_custom_theme_here"
```

Comment: Why was this answer disliked? This worked for me.

Comment: Because the question is about drawable not color.