# How to set a cardview drawable background?

Tags: android

How to solve this question?

```
holder.cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.in_message_bg);
```

Comment: I dont have the code this line is a exemple code

Comment: You don't have the code? That's your bug... Have you tried setBackgroundDrawable?

Comment: You cannot change background drawable because `CardView` uses background drawable to draw the card. But maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33920684/6017001) will help ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
card.setCardBackgroundColor(R.drawable.circle)
```

or You could try via xml

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        card:cardBackgroundColor="#ff00ff"
        card:cardElevation="4dp">
```

Hope this works.