# Setting CardView elevation programmatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, elevation, cardview

I do not know if this approach is the best, but I have the following problem:

I want a list item (a CardView) in a RecyclerView to be animated when it's button was clicked, so that this button, some other views inside this item and the background of the CardView changes.

I am catching the animateChange from a custom RecyclerView.ItemAnimator:
(until now the animation is just a fade defined in the xml via animateLayoutChanges)

```
public boolean animateChange(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
    Log.d("Animation", "Test");
    final MyAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyAdapter.MyViewHolder) newHolder;

    viewHolder.mButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.mHints.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = viewHolder.containerCardView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = 192;
    viewHolder.containerCardView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    viewHolder.containerCardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.some_background);
    viewHolder.containerCardView.setElevation(20f);

    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I am setting the background manually in the animateChange. Everything works fine (or lets say at least as expected) except for the elevation of the CardView. I tried to set the elevation by hand, but there is no elevation shown.

EDIT______

My CardView has an ImageView and a button inside it. When pressing the button, the button itself and the picture should fade out and there shall be a red line on the right side of the cardView. I tried to achieve that by setting the background (with setBackgroundResource) to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="180"
            android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:centerX="0.1"
            android:startColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="2dip"
            android:bottomRightRadius="2dip"
            android:topLeftRadius="2dip"
            android:topRightRadius="2dip"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:right="4dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Which is just an xml drawable with a red line on the right. Do you have any suggestions for another way to approach my goal?

Comment: `I tried to set the elevation by hand, but there is no elevation shown` What do you mean?

Comment: viewHolder.containerCardView.setElevation(20f); The cardView has an elevation before, but not after I set a new background. So I tried to set it again with this line of code.

Comment: Why don't you just set it in XML?

Comment: The CardView has an elevation in XML, but has none after setting the background to it.

Comment: @Vancore this is exactly the reason why you are not seeing any shadow.

Comment: Yeah I guessed so. Maybe my approach is not correct then. I will update my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should call [`setCardElevation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setCardElevation(float)) rather than `setElevation`. The second one modifies the property [`elevation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:elevation), which all `View` subclasses have since Lollipop (API level 21).

And **DON'T USE** `setBackgroundResource`: the card background is its elevation (this because the card is compatible with all Android versions before Lollipop, which don't have the `elevation` property). Use `setCardBackgroundColor` to set a background color (or `app:cardBackgroundColor` in your xml).

If you need a background image, rather than a color, place an `ImageView` inside of your card as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33920684/1507512) suggests.

Do what you want, but DON'T call any `setBackground...` method on the `CardView`, or you will lose the card shadow (its elevation effect).

Secondly, to animate your elevation use the following code:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cardView, "cardElevation", start, end);
// if needed set duration, interpolator, or what you want on the animator
animator.start();
```

Comment: Does your card is contained inside of another layout? The elevation shadow could simply be not visible because of the `clipChildren` and `clipToPadding` properties of the container layout (which are `true` by default).

Comment: I updated the answer. Your code has some problem related to a wrong usage of `View`'s methods.

Comment: My cardView was indeed inside a RelativeLayout. I deleted the parent RelativeLayout, since my cardView is a row item of the recyclerView, but still no changes. Problem is that i cannot simply use a backgroundColor, because i want to have  specific background (with only a red line on the right side)

Comment: `CardView` is an extension of `FrameLayout`: so place an `ImageView` as first son of the card and put your background as `src` of this ImageView (eventually with a right `scaleType`). http://stackoverflow.com/a/33920684/1507512

Comment: I updated the answer to explain how to animate the elevation correctly when the card view is clicked

Comment: The approach with the ImageView as first child seems to work, although I have some layoutGravity problems (but this is probably another problem)

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
cardview.setMaxCardElevation();
```

but note that:

> Calling this method has no effect if device OS version is Lollipop or
>   newer and getUseCompatPadding() is false.

Or try

```
cardview.setCardElevation();
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setCardElevation(float))

**Or from xml:**

Add `android:clipChildren="false"` to the parent of your cardview or add a small amount of padding to your View and set `android:clipToPadding="false"`

and use

```
card_view:cardElevation="VALUE"
```

Comment: clipTopadding and clipChildren seem to have no effect on this. I think the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @Vancore unfortunately I am out of ideas !

Answer (score 1):

The View's [`Outline`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html) is what "drives the shape of its shadows". When changing the background implicitly changes the view's outline, you must explicitly invalidate the outline by calling [`View.invalidateOutline()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidateOutline()), for the shadows to be redrawn around the view.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, try to explain a little bit your answer. Answers with just a few words and some links should be added as comments not answers.